# Domain Model Financial Trading application

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design

my company is thinking about implementing a new financial compliance trading application which is an application that would check all trades that would be executed by the company.  A very simple check might be "Don't Invest in Stocks that sell Alcohol" for example.

We need to define a financial business object model and then design the actual rule engine.  Some potential data models would be Security, Trade, Derivative, etc.

My question does any one know where I could look at some Financial Domain Model already written that would be a good starting place for us to begin our analysis?

We don't want to re-invent the wheel and coming up with an existing financial object model would be very helpful.
Thanks all

Comment: I would check http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/search?q=schema.org if I were you. 4 years later :D :D :D By designing a domain model it is a good starting point to check linked data vocabs.

Answer (score 3):

You could check out the [FPML](http://www.fpml.org/) spec. for some ideas about how to model your data.  However, I'd recommend only browsing it to get an idea of the domain objects you might need - Don't try to copy it as it's almost certainly too complex / detailed for your needs.

In fact for domain-specific data such as you describe I've found it's almost always better to build rather than buy (cheaper, faster, easier to change, easier to understand, better fit within your fitm).  However, you might want to consider a 3rd party engine for implementing your actual rules component (e.g. [Drools](http://jboss.org/drools)).

Comment: Totally agree with the Drools comment.

Comment: I've used Drools in another project that performed Post-Trade Rule Checking and I would not nor never use this package again.  I did not see the value add of this product.  We started using Drools right when JBoss purchased the project and felt like they abandoned this so where was little support and help for this effort.  I would not use Drools again, but would consider using another rules engine.

Comment: @Peter: I'm sorry to hear that.  We use Drools although perhaps not extensively enough to have come across these problems.  I'm actually a bigger fan of coding business rules by hand where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your problem domain is rather different, because you basically want an rule-driven system, but if you want to see a very good object model for financial applications, see [Quantlib](http://quantlib.org). It's open-source, and it's *extremely* well documented. It approaches the problem from a option pricing perspective, but it might give you some ideas anyway. As an example, [see how they have modelled a swap](http://quantlib.org/reference/class_quant_lib_1_1_swap.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check ["Analysis Patterns: Reusable Object Models"](http://www.martinfowler.com/books.html#ap), a book by Martin Fowler. The book include some useful examples to think about financial domains and OO analysis.

Comment: Check this out. His trading model does not have the breath of objects I am looking for.  Don't believe will be a good fit for my project; thanks

Answer (score 0):

Building your own finance domain model is hard if your not experienced. Your completely right to be looking for examples.

If your company if serious about build a proper product that will be successfully they must hire someone with such experience.

Apart from that expect your model to change a lot as the product is developed.

Best of luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to Bloomberg or another market data provider ? They will not give you a model per-se but you can see all the various data fields that are available on a per instrument basis. That should give you a good start in shaping your class properties and also help in determining the class hierarchy.

You should also bear in mind the scope of the system - even commercial system vendors in this space often "flatten" their security models to just one table and use redundant fields and perhaps a few lookup tables. It really depends on the complexity of the instruments you will be trading and what rules you want.

There are also numerous Business RUle Engines (paid and open source) on the market so don't re-invent the wheel unless you have to - generally most are based on the RETE algorithm from what I have seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm